# Error in Django migrations, no changes detected

Tags: python, django, mongodb, migration, djongo

I've correctly done the "initial setup" with *python manage.py migrate* command and now in my mongodb database I see these collections:

```
__schema__
auth_group
auth_group_permissions
auth_permission
auth_user
auth_user_groups
auth_user_user_permissions
django_admin_log
django_content_type
django_migrations
django_session
```

with object inside them so I'm pretty sure that I did it correctly and if I do it now it says:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I think this is all normal, then i created this models.py file

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Here is part of my settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mysite',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Folder Structure:

```
mysite
  mysite
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    other files
  polls
    migrations
    other files
      __init__.py
```

When I try to do *python manage.py makemigrations* I get this "No changes detected". Adding my app name doesn't solve the problem. I have a migrations folder with init.py (with the __) in it. I don't understand why it worked for the initial setup and now it doesn't. If i put some syntax error in the **models.py** file the messages I get after running the commands are the same, so maybe models.py is being searched in another folder? Really don't know, anyway hope i wrote everything necessary, I will reply as fast as I can if you need more informations!

Comment: It looks like you didn't add your app to the `INSTALLED_APPS`. Django here only checks `admin`, `auth`, `contenttypes` and `sessions`, and these are some apps Django implemented itself.

Comment: Forgot to say that I also did this! here is that part of code: 
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mysite',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
Sorry, don't know how to write it better

Comment: You can include the section about `INSTALLED_APPS` in your post.

Comment: `'mysite'` is the name of the app?

Comment: Honestly, i have a bit of confusion of what is my app name, but if i run 
python manage.py makemigrations mysite then it says: No changes detected in app 'mysite'
If instead of mysite i write 'polls' it says No installed app with label 'polls'.
These names come from the django beginner tutorial

Comment: `I have a migrations folder with init.py` any other file ?

Comment: There is only init.py file

Comment: If you are not sure about app name, show your folder structure or the folder in which this models.py lies is your app name.

Comment: do you mean `__init__.py` or init.py?  The migration folder should have a `__init__.py `instead of init.py.

Comment: the file is `__init__.py`, i've added the folder structure in the post

Comment: in that case, you can try a few things,  (1) deleting all the 000*.py files and do makemigrations again;  (2) go to you db shell, try to show entries in your django_migrations table, see if there is anything where app='mysite', if they are there, you can delete the rows. try makemigrations again

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time, i finally solved this thanks to the accepted answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a few things to check to make sure your migrations will go through.

1. Make sure you created the app using `django-admin startapp mysite`.
2. Make sure you've saved the models file after adding the model into the `mysite/models.py`.
3. Add the app name to the installed app in the settings.py, but make sure to add it after all apps.

In your case I see that you've added `mysite` in the installed app when in reality you should add the app name not the project name, which in your case the `polls` app.

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem was the incorrect app name, this solved the problem, do you know why i have to put the app name after all the others and not before?